# In css3, how to clip inner transformed `position:absolute` element using outer element's border?

Tags: html, css, transform

Below is the snippet:

```css
.out {
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    
}

.in {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translate3d(-20%, -40%, 0px) scale(0.7);
    position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<div class="out">
    <div class="in">
    </div>
    
</div>
```

As can be seen, the inner element (red square) goes out of the border/bound of the outer element (green square).

Does anyone have ideas about how to clip the part of inner element which goes out of the border of the outer element?

--

I find `overflow: hidden` doesn't work well because of the `position: absolute` property in the inner element..

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden` on the outer element:

```css
.out {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    
}

.in {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translate3d(-20%, -40%, 0px) scale(0.7);

}
```

```html
<div class="out">
    <div class="in">
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the `overflow:hidden` won't work if I set `position: absolute` for inner element..  http://jsfiddle.net/jLuype7h/

Comment: your welcome, Yes your right overflow:hidden good for this issue

Comment: Of course it won't work with absolute positioning, as that takes the element out of the rendering stack. There's no solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one:

```
.out {
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
     overflow:hidden;
}

.in {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translate3d(-20%, -40%, 0px) scale(0.7);


}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/xveLy37m/)

Comment: Why do you insist on posting answers that mirror another existing answer long time after it has been posted. The other answer was posted a whole 15 minutes earlier. This is the second or third time that I am seeing you do this.